# Using the URLconf defined in lec3.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: admin/ hello/ The empty path didn't match any of these

Tags: python, html, django

these are my main codes i wrote to create wepapp but i get this 404 error so pleas help
my hello urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from hello import views

urlpatterns = [
   path("", views.index, name="index")
]
```

my urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('hello/', include("hello.urls")),
]
```

my views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("hello, orld")
```

Comment: could you show your template where you call index view?

Comment: from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index")

Comment: `from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index") `

Comment: no, i meant the template where you write something like ```{% url 'index' %}```

Comment: according to the source i am learning from this is all and it should work

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to access `index` with

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/`. This will not work, because your `index` is included in `hello`'s urls.py, and `hello`'s url starts with `hello/`.

Try

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello
```

instead.